# How does JVM and spring container work together during objs or beans creation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, classloader, spring-ioc, spring-context

Spring container creates `Beans` by creating a DAG first and then instantiates the non-dependent `beans` before creating any `beans` that are dependent on other `beans`. This is fine and understood. Any `beans` that is are dependent on regular java `objects` / pojo's could be supplied by JVM classloader mechanism and that fine too.

But any java object that's dependent on a bean is what causing me to understand this interleaved mechanism bit more in depth.

1. in simple case - JVM can wait for the spring container to finish its bean creation process and then JVM can create any java objs it has to.

**and**

2. for interleaved beans and java objs: they both (jvm and spring container) will create beans and java objs in an interleaved fashion as required. I think of this because, when a bean can have a ref to regular java obj and a in turn a java obj could have a bean as dependency.

So, Just to clarify - does Spring Container and JVM create beans and obj's in interleaved fashion.

(This is a Q to understand the working of Spring Container along side JVM, this can not be specific to a class or seceniro or use case, so please don't mark this question as lacking somthing like specifics or use case or somthing else -- Thanks for understanding.)

Edit following @BoristheSpider comment:
Take some `spring bean`. Spring container will try to create this `bean`. Now, say, this `bean` is depended on a `pojo`. So now, how is this `pojo` created. Is it created by Spring Container  directly or by delegating it to the respective JVM classloader (bootstrap or ext or application). I am thinking it will delegate it to corresponding JVM classloader. someone can clarify this.
NEXT - when JVM has to create a `pojo` which is dependent on `bean` how does it know about the bean. So JVM and Spring Container has to care about one and other. How to they work hand-in-hand is what I am trying to uderstand.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. The JVM doesn’t care about Spring nor does it need to. Does your browser care that you’re planning to visit Stackoverflow when you first open it? Of course not - they’re different _layers_.

Comment: You will get much more productive answers if you provide a specific example that confuses you!

Comment: JVM has **nothing** to do with Spring, at all. The only relation you might think of is that Spring is written on top of JavaSE and JavaEE specifications, and Java applications run inside JVM, that's it; however, this in no way constitutes any relation of JVM and Spring when creating beans. Bean is just an object managed by Spring container. When you buy the car, car manufacturer doesn't care where you drive it.

Comment: This is a very good question which I really understand. 2 years after, no reply? hm :/